# Flex column except one child with flex order

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to push the `.last-row` which uses an flex order to the next row while keeping the rest of the list at top in column?

```css
ul{width: 100%;display: flex;list-style:none;}
li{flex: 0 0 25%;height: 40px;background: salmon;text-align:center}
li.last-row{order:1;background: maroon; flex: 0 0 100%;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Col</li>
  <li>Col</li>
  <li class="last-row">row</li>
  <li>Col</li>
  <li>Col</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `.last-row` and not `last-order`:

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 40px;
  background: salmon;
  text-align: center;
  order: 1;
}

li.last-row {
  order: 2;
  background: maroon;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Col</li>
  <li>Col</li>
  <li class="last-row">row</li>
  <li>Col</li>
  <li>Col</li>
</ul>
```

You need to set the order of the the `li` without class to `1`, the `.last-row` to `2`, and then make sure your flex parent `ul` is set to allow wrapping `flex-wrap: wrap`;

Comment: you don't need to define order:1 for the other element. Having order:1 (like the OP did) is enought

Comment: @TemaniAfif sure, but in cases like this, I tend to error on the side of "if someone else reads this code, they'll know what I was doing."